# Styling Gnome Terminal Window

Tags: gnome3, gnome-terminal

We're running Rocky 8 Gnome Classic desktop. After a recent update the Gnome terminal window switched from a light gray to a very dark gray frame and title bar which is hard to distinguish from our desktop background. The old light gray color worked fine. I cannot find a stylesheet or dconf setting to modify this. Other application windows are still using the light gray setting, only Gnome Terminal seems to be different. Using Adwaita default theme.